# Windows 8 with UEFI dual boot kali linux 1.0.9

Tags: linux, windows, boot, multi-boot

I have an Asus x551ca with a windows 8.1 and works with UEFI. I'm starting to like very much of kali linux and I want do dual boot with it and windows.

I make the disc partition, make the bootable pendrive with kali linux 1.0.9.iso, make a graphical instalation everything goes right until the instalation with no grub error. But when I restart no sign of kali linux and he goes directly to windows.

I already try bcdeasy,easyuefi and the some tutorials of dualbooting. I'm starting to question me why after the installation I restart and go to UEFI and the partition of the kali or ubuntu ( already try dual with Ubuntu too) not appear in boot, only CD/DVD ROM and windows manager boot.

I would like some help please and the same time let this question: after the installation if I go to uefi/boot and tap in add new entry (I don't know the path but if I know)) can I run kali linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) Boot Manager?
There's a good guide at https://wiki.debian.org/GrubEFIReinstall.

rEFInd will parse your hard drive for installed kernels, and provide you a graphic menu to boot them.

I combed the net for a bit on this issue as I had the same problem once but I can't for the life of me remember how I fixed it (I still can't). Here's what I found though.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#UEFI_systems -
Some UEFI firmwares require a bootable file at a known location before they will show UEFI NVRAM boot entries. If this is the case, grub-install will claim efibootmgr has added an entry to boot GRUB, however the entry will not show up in the VisualBIOS boot order selector.

The solution is to place a file at one of the known locations. Assuming the EFI partition is at /boot/efi/ this will work:

```
mkdir /boot/efi/EFI/boot
cp /boot/efi/EFI/grub/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi
```

Maybe changing the .efi stub name & directory will sort it out for you? Or perhaps just installing into the right location to start with would be best (The link above has an install section).

This GRUB troubleshooting entry found at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Arch_not_found_from_other_OS might be of relevance to you also.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answer and sorry so now i can reply.
yes i already install the rEFInd and only show windows.
i cant create a mkdir becouse he dont allow.
im trying this such a long time  im exaust and let me say: i m tired and i dont think i can do this.im just askme why can i install kali in the windows envoirment like any other program, and keep me doing that error in instalation "missing g2ldr.mbr".
anyway microsoft wins by now.
thanks for your time one more time.
Anglose

Answer (score 0):

ok
i already got it. finally i win microsoft.. lool
the problem was the grubx64.efi and bootx64.efi. in paste efi/boot/ the files didnt work the i change one the ubuntu boot and another from fedora and finally the mix work with rEFInd.
now i have windows 8.1/kali linux and ubuntu in my asus x551cap.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you disable secure boot and enable legacy mode
for detail explanation check this [**dual boot kali linux with windows 10**](http://www.techyguide.net/dual-boot-kali-linux-windows-10/)